# Instagram API и взаимодействие двух скриптов

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram, instagram-api

Для получение фотографий с инстаграма по определенным хэштегам я использую скрипт **Instafeed.js**, нужно, чтобы скрипт работал с данным скриптом: [Альбом](http://tympanus.net/Development/Stapel/index.html).

Для получение фотографий сразу с несколькими хэштегами, есть вариант: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hm6cz4of/4/).

HTML

```
<h3>tag 1</h3>
    <div id="telegramG"></div>
<h3>tag 2</h3>
    <div id="whatsappG"></div>
<h3>tag 3</h3>
    <div id="facebookG"></div>
```

CSS

```css
.insta-pic {
    background-color: #fcc;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
}
h3 {
    float: left;
    clear:both;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

JS

```
function getMultipleTags(tags, client) {
    var feeds = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = tags.length; i < len; i++) {
        feeds.push(new Instafeed({
            // rest of your options
            get: 'tagged',
            tagName: tags[i],
            target: tags[i] + "G",
            limit: 3,
            clientId: client,
            template: '<div class="insta-pic"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a></div>'
        }));
    }
    return feeds;
}
var client = '9a7750944a1d42ba8d93f7aaa4767b5e';
if (client) {
    // get multiple tags
    var myTags = getMultipleTags(['telegram', 'whatsapp', 'facebook'], client);
    // run each instance
    for (var i = 0, len = myTags.length; i < len; i++) {
        myTags[i].run();
    }
}
```

Не получается взаимодействовать два скрипта.